# Separate terminal windows for input and output streams

Tags: gnome-terminal, c++, xterm

How do I use different xterm or terminal windows for input and output streams while programming in C++ such that I enter input in one terminal window and get output in another window?

Comment: Please see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009433/linux-terminal-emulator-with-separate-input-area-and-output-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your C program write its output to a text file and have the second terminal watch that text file using

```
tail -f myfile.txt
```